# php with MariadB calling stored procedure using JSON_ARRAYAGG JSON_OBJECT returns data but also the query (?)

Tags: php, mariadb

A mariaDB stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `db`.`test`(IN STR varchar (128))
BEGIN
     SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('AMNT', AMNT) ) FROM BOMI AS RES;
END
```

is called by php in a function as follows:

```
mysqli_query($link ,"SET @p0='".$param1."'");
mysqli_multi_query ($link, "CALL test(@p0)") OR DIE (mysqli_error($link));
$data = [];
if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) 
{
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
   {
      $data[] = $row;
   }
}
return array ($status, $code, $message, $data);
```

the caller prints the data:

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

The data returned in $data is correct as an array of 3 records

Though [Q1] the result has the query itself as a prefix.
Is this correct ?

```
`[{"JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('AMNT', AMNT) )":"[{\"AMNT\": 1.0000},{\"AMNT\": 1.0000},{\"AMNT\": 1.0000}]"}]
`
```

and [Q2] the data has backward slashes. (yes, a (hack) with stripslashes() works but, how to avoid  ?)

MariaDB  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.11.2-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
PHP 8.1.12-1ubuntu4.3 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2023 17:37:48) (NTS)

Expected:

```
'"[{"AMNT": 1.0000},{"AMNT": 1.0000},{"AMNT": 1.0000}]"}]'
```

Comment: I've edited to make it more clear that you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are different products, and they are growing more and more incompatible.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($$conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: That isn't the query, that's the column name. You don't set an alias and you fetch by name (`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`), so it uses the whole expression.

Comment: And you are encoding what already comes as JSON from the DB.

Comment: B.T.W mysql --version gives: ** mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.11.2-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper ** AND mariadb --version gives:  **mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.11.2-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper **

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hints. Changes it as follows:

**Query**

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('AMNT', AMNT) AS RESULT ) FROM BOMI;
```

I use `printn_r()` the output is this:

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [RESULT] => [{"AMNT": 1.0000},{"AMNT": 1.0000},{"AMNT": 1.0000}]
        )
)
```

When I use this:

```
$data = $data[0]["RESULT"];
```

Then the output is this:

```
[{"AMNT": 1.0000},{"AMNT": 1.0000},{"AMNT": 1.0000}]
```